Existence of pairwise quasi-complementary but not complementary subspaces
Let $$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space (complex or real). A subspace of $$ means a closed linear submanifold. Subspaces $M$ and $N$ of $X$ are quasi-complementary if $M\cap N=\{0\}$ and $M+N$ is dense in $X$. In the case $M+N=X$ we say that $M$ and $N$ are complementary.
Question. If $n\geq 2$, do there exist subspaces $M_1,\ldots, M_n$ of $X$ which are pairwise quasi-complementary but not complementary, that is,
$$ M_i\cap M_j=\{0\},\quad \overline{M_i+M_j}=X,\quad \text{but}\quad M_i+M_j\ne X\quad (1\leq i< j\leq n).$$
My question is related to the problem of realization of an abstract lattice as a subspace lattice. For instance, the pentagon cannot be realized in a finite-dimensional Banach space,
however, it can be realized as a subspace lattice in the infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space (Halmos: Reflexive lattices of subspaces). I would like to know if the pentagon (and some other abstract lattices) can be realized in a (infinite-dimensional) Banach space that is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

I'm not sure what do you mean exactly by your last question: you can take a lattice of subspaces of a Hilbert space, and just take direct sum with anything non-Hilbert. One way to make sense of this is to ask whether a pentagon realisable by non-complemented subspaces. But this is still trivially true...

Denis T, can you please explain your construction in more detail? A realization of the pentagon in a given Banach space $X$ would be a subspace lattice with non-trivial subspaces $M$, $N$, and $K$ of $X$ such that $M\wedge K={0}$, $M\vee N=X$, and $N\subsetneq K$. Here $\wedge$ is the intersection and $\vee$ is closure of the sum. Of course, the pentagon can be realizes is some Banach spaces, but can be it realized in any infinite-dimensional Banach space?

Regarding the last paragraph: A lattice is modular iff it doesn't contain a pentagon (e.g. p.80 in  Grätzer's book https://books.google.ca/books?id=SoGLVCPuOz0C&pg=PA80) A closed subspace lattice of a Banach space $E$ is modular iff $E$ is finite dimensional (e.g. p.144 in Maeda & Maeda 's book https://books.google.ca/books?id=p8DqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA144 )

Together; If $E$ is infinite dimensional Banach space, then its closed subspace lattice contains a pentagon.

@Onur Oktay Thank you for the comment! It seems to me that this solves my problem for the case $n=2$, that is, the existence of two subspaces that are quasi-complementary but not complementary.

Why, @JankoBracic? The join of the pentagon need not be the entire space.

Yes, you are right! However, the situation where there is a Banach space such that its closed subspace lattice contains a pentagon, but the pentagon cannot be realized in that Banach space as a subspace lattice, would be strange. But of course, I have no evidence that it is not possible.

It would be very interesting if there were an infinite-dimensional Banach space in which the pentagon could not be realized. That would mean in some sense that the closed subspace lattice of it "is modular in the upper part". I hope that you understand what I mean.

It is well known that every subspace $Y$ of a separable Banach space $X$ is quasi-complemented.We denote its quasi-complement by $Z$. This is a classical result due to F. J. Murray and G. Mackey.The proof is based on the existence of $\{(y_n, f_n)_{n} \cup (z_n, g_n)_n \}$ which is a biorthogonal system of $X$ with $(y_n)_n, (z_n)_n $ generate the subspaces $Y,Z$ respectively and $(\bigcap_n \operatorname{Ker} f_n) \cap(\bigcap_n \operatorname{Ker} g_n) = \{ 0 \}, $
Theorem : Let $ X $ be a separable Banach space, $Y$ be an infinite dimensional subspace with infinite dimension quasi-complement $Z$.
Choose $(y_k,f_k)_{k\in N}$, $(z_k, g_k)_{k\in N}$  the biorthogonal system associated to $Y, Z$.
For a given $n\in N$ choose $(a_i, b_i)_{i=1}^n$ in the unit sphere  of $R^2$ with $a_ib_j - b_ia_j \neq 0$
and for each $i= 1\dots n$ set $M_i$ be the closed linear span of the sequence $\{a_iy_k+b_iz_k\}_k$.
Then for every $i \neq j$ the subspaces $M_i , M_j $ satisfy
$M_i \cap M_j = \{0\}$ and $M_i + M_j$ dense in $X$.
Proof : Fix $i \neq j$ and consider the following biorthogonal system
$\{ (a_iy_k + b_iz_k, b_jf_k - a_jg_k)_k\cup (a_jy_k + b_jz_k, b_if_k - a_ig_k)_k$.
This corresponds to the pair $M_i M_j$.  It is easy to see that $ (y_k)_k \cup (z_k)_k \subset M_i + M_j $ hence $M_i + M_j$  is dense in $X$.
For similar reasons
$\langle \{ b_jf_k-a_jg_k \}_k \cup \{ b_if_k-a_ig_k \}_k \rangle = \langle \{f_k\}_k \cup \{g_k\}_k \rangle $
which is $ w^* $ dense in $X^*$.Hence
$(\bigcap_k \operatorname{Ker} b_jf_k- a_jg_k) \cap(\bigcap_k \operatorname{Ker} b_if_k-a_ig_k) = \{ 0 \}$
which yields that  $M_i \cap M_j = \{0\}$.
Remark 1 : Clearly there exists a sequence $\{M_i\}_{i\in N}$
satisfying the conclusion of the theorem.
Remark 2 : The theorem remains valid for non separable reflexive Banach spaces and more generally for WCG spaces.
Indeed let $X$ be a WCG space. From Amir Lindenstrauss theorem there exists a family $(P_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ mutually orthogonal  bounded projections such that for each $\alpha\in A$  we have that $P_{\alpha}(X)$ is separable and $\langle \bigcup_{\alpha}P_{\alpha}(X) \rangle$ is dense in $X$.
For a fixed $ n\in N$ and every $ \alpha\in A$ choose a family $(M_i^{\alpha})_{i=1}^n$ of closed subspaces of $P_{\alpha}(X)$ which are pairwise quasi-complemented in $P_{\alpha}(X)$.
For $ i= 1\dots n$ set $M_i = \overline{\langle\bigcup_{\alpha}M_i^{\alpha}\rangle}$. The family $(M_i)_{i=1}^n$ has the desided property.Indeed it is clear that for $i \neq j$ $ M_i + M_j $ is dense in $X$. To see that $M_i \cap M_j =\{ 0 \}$ assume on the contrary that there exists $x \in M_i \cap M_j$ with $x\neq 0$.Then there exists $ \alpha\in A$ such that $P_{\alpha}(x) \neq 0$.Since $P_{\alpha}(M_q) = M_q^{\alpha}$ for all $q= 1\dots n$ we  derive a contradiction.
I also found interesting the question, stated by Janko Bracic, if the spaces $(M_i)_i$ could be selected to be pairwise isomorphic. It has an affirmative answer  and is explained below.
Remark 3 : Assume that for all $k\in N$ $\|f_k\| = \|g_k\|=1$ and $f_k(y_k) = g_k(z_k) =1$.For $i= 1 \dots n $ and $k\in N$ choose $a_i^k, b_i^k$ and $\epsilon_k > 0$ such that the following hold.

For $i \neq j$ $\frac{1}{|a_i^k|}(|a_i^k - a_j^k|\|y_k\| + |b_i^k - b_j^k|\|z_k\|) < \epsilon_k$ and $\sum_k \epsilon_k < \frac{1}{2}$.

For every $k\in N$ and $i\neq j$ we have $a_i^k, a_j^k  \neq0$ and $ a_i^k b_j^k- b_i^ka_j^k\neq 0$.


Define
$M_i = \overline { \langle (a_i^ky_k + b_i^kz_k)_k \rangle}$
It follows easily that the new family $(M_i)_{i=1}^n$ satisfies the conclusion of the theorem.We claim that the spaces are pairwise isomorphic.
Indeed let $ y_i = \sum_{k=1}^l c_k(a_i^ky_k + b_i^kz_k)$ be a normalized vector in $M_i$. Then $|f_k (y_i)| =|c_ka_i^k|\leq 1$ hence $|c_k|\leq \frac{1}{|a_i^k|}$.
This yields that $\|y_i -y_j\|\leq \frac{1}{2}$ which shows that $M_i, M_j$ are isomorphic.
Remark 4 : There is something which I could not understand.
If $M_i, M_j$ are spaces as in Remark 3 then $\operatorname{dist} (B_{M_i}, B_{M_j}) = 0$. Hence $M_i, M_j$ are not a complemented pair. But if the initial subspaces $Y, Z$ are a complemented pair then $M_i + M_j = Y+Z= X$
hence $M_i, M_j$ is a complemented pair. Any help?
Remark 5 : There is no problem concerning the proof of Remark 3.
My false was that I consider that $M_i + M_j = Y+Z$. What actually we have is that $\langle (y_k)_k \cup (z_k)_k \rangle \subset M_i +M_j$ which does not imply that $\overline {\langle (y_k)_k \rangle} + \overline{ \langle (z_k)_k \rangle} \subset M_i +M_j$.
Therefore Remark 3 yields that independently to what is the initial quasi-complemented pair $Y,Z$( complemented or not) the $(M_i)_i$ resulting from Remark 3, since  $\operatorname{dist} (B_{M_i}, B_{M_j}) = 0$, are pairwise quasi-complemented  but not complemented.
Hence Remark 3 answers completely the posed question for separable and WCG spaces.

@S Argyros Thank you for the answer! Is there any hope for the existence of subspaces $M_j$ in the case when $X$ is not separable? I know that Lindenstrauss proved that every subspace of a reflexive Banach space is quasi-complemented. Hence, if $X$ is reflexive and not isomorphic to a Hilbert space there exists a subspace which is quasi-complemented but not complemented (for a Hilbert space we can construct such a subspaces using an orthogonal basis).

Thus, this answers my question for a reflexive space $X$ and two subspaces. But I don't see how to prove the existence of three or more subspaces which are pairwise quasi-complemented but not complemented (should they be isomorphic subspaces?).

The theorem states that for every separable Banach space $X$ (reflexive or not) and every $n\in N$ there exists $(M_i)_{i=1}^n$ closed subspaces which are mutually quasi-complement.The remark states that this family could be an infinite sequence.

Concerning non separable spaces this approach has some difficulties to be applied.

A proof for WCG spaces has been added in Remark 2.

Re: Remark 3. If you start with an $M$-basis for which every splitting of the sequence into two parts gives a complemented pair, then the $M$-basis is actually an uncondtional basis. In that case the space has another Schauder basis that is conditional, so you can start with that conditional basis.

My problem is that I do not see something wrong in the proof of Remark 3 or the theorem itself. The proof does not depend from the nature of the M basis. At the same time Remark 4 explains that in some cases the proof of Remark 3 leads to a contradiction. So at least in Remark 3 there is something invalid that unfortunately I could not see it.
